# How to prevent sublasses from default implementing a method of super class?

Tags: java

I have a method which adds Objects to an static list like this:

```
@PostConstruct
protected void registerToTransactionList() {
    TransactionValidator.registerTransactionList(this);
}
```

`registerTransactionList` method just adds "this" to the static list, this method is in `BalanceTransactionValidator` class which extends `TransactionValidator` (owner of static list),the problem is all subclasses of `BalanceTransactionValidator` class are added to static list either,and if I override `registerToTransactionList` method in them like this:

```
@Override
@PostConstruct
protected void registerToTransactionList() {
}
```

It doesn't add subclasses but doesn't add `BalanceTransactionValidator` either. Can anybody help me on this? Please notice sublasses are overriding this method by default.

Comment: And for the record: the code you are showing is not adding **classes**. It is adding "this" objects. If it would be really about classes, the code would be like "this.getClass()" or something alike!

Comment: you are right my mistake I edited

Answer (score 1):

make the method **private** to block the visibility

```
private void registerToTransactionList() {
}
```

or make the method **final** [to block it from been override](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/final.html)

```
protected final void registerToTransactionList() {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are **two** ways of achieving that:

1. Keep your method as it is; but then you have to actively check for the type of your objects before externally calling that method
2. Change your whole logic and make that method **private**

It won't help to make the method **final** as suggested in one of the comments - your problem is not that subclasses are overwriting that method; in essence, you have a design problem: you wish that subclasses should not invoke that method at all.

So, the **only** real option that makes sense here is "2.". You see, by having **public** method on a class that you **want** to be extended you are implicitly saying: it is perfectly fine to call that method; on any object that is instance of the base class (or child class!).

And in your case, that is not true: you actually do **not** want that the code behind this method runs for child classes. Then you shouldn't put that method in the list of public/protected methods of your base class!

Finally: you might want to step back and do some reading about good OO design. Class hierarchies do not fall from the sky: you willfully design them for a certain purpose. In other words: there is more to inheritance than just putting some "A extends B" on your class declaration. You have to understand each and every method on your B class; and how your child classes should deal with them!

EDIT: after some more thinking, I guess you are doing things "the wrong way", like:

```
class BaseClass {

  public final void doRegistration() {
    BaseClass toRegister = getObjectForRegistration();
    if (toRegister != null) { ... register  toRegister ...
  }

  protected BaseClass getObjectForRegistration() {
     return null;
  }
```

With that code, you could then put

```
 protected BaseClass getObjectForRegistration() {
    if (this instanceof ClassThatShouldBeRegistered) {
      return this;
    } 
    return null;
 }
```

into that one class that wants to be registered. Probably there could be even nicer ways of doing so; but after some thinking I don't see how we could avoid the *instanceof*. But the above code should work; and it only requires specific code only in your base class and in that one class that wants to register something.

Comment: I forgot to add that even making method private doesn't help still all subclasses are added to list

Comment: I updated my answer to give some hints there. Hope that helps.

Comment: I have tried this and yet not working for me I don't know why,It is logically true but not working

Comment: Then you probably did something wrong. We cant help with code that we dont see. In that sense: rework your question; put in a **minimal** viable example that shows your problem. You have a lot of **descriptions** in your question; you should replace them with *code*, because descriptions always imply *interpretation*, and I guess: your code is wrong, you interpret that the wrong way, and thus you come to wrong conclusions.